# Stream Reader to double System.FormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, yahoo-finance

I want to convert yahoo csv stock prices to a C# double array.
This is my code:

```
WebRequest wrPrice = WebRequest.Create("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + sSymbols + "&f=a"); //sSymbols zb. "AAPL+GOOG+MSFT"
    WebResponse wResp = wrPrice.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream());
    double[] dCurrentPrice = new double[iStockTableRows];
    int iLine = 0;
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        dCurrentPrice[iLine] = double.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
        iLine++;
    }
    sr.Close();
```

The integer iStockTableRows is the amount of stocks.
The string sSymbols contains the stock symbols, it can look like this: "AAPL+MSFT"

The CSV file looks like this:

```
128.61
544.98
```

When I run it System.FormatException occurs in this line:

```
dCurrentPrice[iLine] = double.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
```

First it worked and for some reason the same error occurs again.
When I write sr.ReadLine() it doesn't return anything.

Comment: The obvious place to start would be to look at what `sr.ReadLine()` is actually returning. Can you include that in your question?

Comment: Also, if you parse nicely the file, make sure on your machine is setup an US locale (or invariant one) like this:double.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @MattBurland it reads the lines from the CSV files that is downloaded through the WebRequest

Comment: @Orlando: Again, if you `var s = sr,ReadLine()` and then you `Debug.WriteLine(s)` what does it *actually* say. Not what do you think it says, what does it *actually* say. Also, does this happen on the *first* item, the *last* item or somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @MattBurland it says 128.61 on the first and 544.98 on the second item. It works now, but still thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dCurrentPrice[iLine] = double.Parse(sr.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Perhaps you are on a non-US computer, with a different decimal separator.